# history.push not loading the list form in react redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a userlist form with new button and edit button.

new is a `<Link to="/usernew"/>`.

In user new form i have a back button like `<link to="/userlist" />`.

User edit form also has back button like this `<link to="/userlist" />` but from new form it redirects to `userlist` but from edit form the path changes in the browser but `userlist` form is not loading.

For editing i use `history.push('/useredit')` to go to `useredit` form. please help me to solve this. Thanks.

I'm using `redux form and react router 4.`

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 0):

You should use withRouter in your component.
See more [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

Comment: Nice! You can vote my answer and resolve your question :D